# Grouping Teams Together After Parsing - NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE

Tags: php, parsing, formatting, foreach

EDIT: Ok I am a bit closer but still need help... http://pastebin.com/9vdhGT2V

Disclaimer: This is my first post after using SO as a resource for quite a while. I am not being lazy I just have exhausted search and I'm close I just need a nudge from some friendly more experienced coders. Thanks in advance!

I am using Simple HTML DOM to run out to Yahoo Sports and grab scores. What I am having trouble with is grouping the two teams that are play together in a table. I know that I will need to count by 2 as it is very predictable I am just having trouble forming it correct.

This is the last piece of working code I have but it does not group by teams playing each other:

http://pastebin.com/0LzrV0Ej

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');
$nbaScores = "http://sports.yahoo.com/nba/scoreboard";
$html = file_get_html($nbaScores);

// Find all game info
foreach($html->find('tr.ysptblclbg5') as $scores){
    echo "<table><tr><td>".$scores->find('td',0)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',1)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',2)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',3)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',4)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',5)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',6)->plaintext. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$scores->find('td',7)->plaintext. "</td></tr></table>";
    }

unset($scores);

?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Yahoo doesn't allow to just grab their pages, it is illegal

Comment: It is not for commercial use.

Comment: @zerkms His issue, not ours; and I don't believe it can be deemed illegal to screen scrape a site, it can only be considered actually illegal to use said data in ways its license doesn't allow.

Comment: for($i = 0, $c = count($scores); $i < $c; $i += 16) { if($i + 16 < $c) { $output .="</table>";

Comment: I figure if I can form it into an array then do another loop on it this way ^^ I can solve this. I am going to keep hacking at it, meantime if anyone wants to give me coding advice instead of legal counsel I would be much obliged (pun intended).

Comment: @zerkms: "grabbing" yahoo pages isn't illegal, processing and publishing them is - otherwise simply visiting yahoo.com could land you (or your browser vendor) with a lawsuit, which would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: the code will now reflect the overtime optional TD. I assume $parse->find("tag[attribute=value]") returns a table of objects that implement ->plaintext.*

*Edit#2: the code will now know which team won a match (using a subtable of $teams).*

*Edit#3: based on comments: corrected parenthesis, corrected the team shifting in the table from edit#1*

Never used that parser, so assuming your parsing methods work (and assuming I didn't get confused in the TD indexes), but anyway here's the logics:

```
$periods=array("QT1","QT2","QT3","QT4","OT","Total");
$scores=array();
$teams=array();
$teamCount=0;
$matchesCount=0;
foreach($html->find('tr.ysptblclbg5') as $parse){
    $teams[$matchesCount][$teamCount]['name']=$parse->find('td',1)->plaintext; //TD#2 contains the team name
    //TDs 3 to 6 contain partial scores, TD#7 contains final score or OT score (in which case TD#8 contains final score), they all have the "yspscores" class
    $pscores=$parse->find('td[class=yspscores]');
    for($i=1;$i<count($pscores);$i++) { //we start at 1 instead of 0 as the first TD grabbed is the one where the team name is written, as it also has the yspscores class
        if($i==count($pscores)-1) //if we are at the total score
            $scores[$matchesCount][$teamCount][$periods[count($periods)-1]]=$pscores[$i]->plaintext;
        $scores[$matchesCount][$teamCount][$periods[$i-1]]=$pscores[$i]->plaintext;//$periods[$i-1] as $periods doesn't have a useless offset like $pscores has (part of edit#3)
    }
    $teamCount++; //finished a team and its scores, getting ready to move to the next
    if($teamCount%2==0) { //true if we just parsed the 2nd team of a match
        if($maxMatchScore>$scores[$matchesCount][1][$periods[count($periods)-1]]) //if 1st team won
            $teams[$matchesCount][0]['win']=1;
        else
            $teams[$matchesCount][1]['win']=1;
        $teamCount=0; //then reset the counter as next team will the first team parsed of next match
        $matchesCount++; //and ready to move to next match
    } else {
        $maxMatchScore=$scores[$matchesCount][0][$periods[count($periods)-1]]; //if in the middle of parsing the match, memorize the total score of the first team, to know later who won
    }
}
```

There you have 2 tables with teams and scores parsed accordingly to each match. Now you can print them the way you want:

```
foreach($teams as $match=>$subarray) { //teams and scores have their indexes coherent, we could have used scores instead, though subarray would have contained the scores instead of the teams (obviously ^^)
    echo "<br /><br />Match #".($match+1).":<br />"; //prints the index of the match in the tables, +1 because "match number zero" is not NBA-friendly...
    foreach($subarray as $id=>$team) { //if we had used scores instead of teams in the global loop, we would have had subarray as id => scoreArray
        if(empty($team['win'])) { //the winner is bold
            $b1="";
            $b2="";
        } else {
            $b1="<b>";
            $b2="</b>";
        }
        echo "Team: ".$b1.$team['name'].$b2.":"; //here team will print with the hyperlink, use a regexp to remove it if needed
        //the following is still valid, but if you need to display a table, you'll have one more TD on matches with OT, which won't look nice
        //foreach($scores[$match][$id] as $scoreType=>$score) { //the table selects one team of one match, and the corresponding subarray gives as keys the type of score (which quarter time, or final score), and as values the score for the paired index.
            //echo $scoreType.":".$score; //prints "qt1:24", or "final:90"
            //echo $scoreType=='final'?'<br />':' / '; //if it is a quarter's score, we separate the next score with a slash, while if it's the final score we <br> (either for the next team or for the next match, as we surely leave this loop, and maybe the previous ine if it was the 2bd team's scores)
        //}
        //version OK for table display or anything else
        foreach($periods as $scoreType) {
            echo $scoreType.":".(empty($scores[$match][$id][$scoreType])?"-":$scores[$match][$id][$scoreType]); //if no OT, we just print "-" where there could have been the OT
            echo $scoreType==$periods[count($periods)-1]?'<br />':' / ';
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code, so there might be some mistypings, but the purpose is for you to have a hint on how to parse the thing in tables, which is easier if you want to focus on your display ;)

However... I have no legal advice for you, sorry ^^

Comment: Pretty epic solution. It is going to take me a bit to digest it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will need to add a few TDs for possible OT games but this is spot on. (check mark) :)

Comment: This will work, I just have to figure out how to adapt it to consider OT games (extra quarters, as they generate more TDs for that) and then how to dump it into tables by matches

Comment: Didn't see that OT thing (I'm not really familiar with the rules, and a "quarter" should be 1/4 of the game ^^). But I checked the Simple HTML Parser you use, the documentation says you can select tags according to their attributes. I'm going to edit my post to make it easier to handle.

Comment: Yes, Yahoo adds 'extra time' or overtime periods in between the 4 quarters and the total. They also append a 'final' next to the winning team which can be very useful for me.

Comment: Sorry OT = overtime or extra periods to decide a game in the event of a tied score after a quarter (or period)

Comment: Now updated to consider the possible OT column and the winner of each match. Not tested though, may be some typing errors, but I think the idea is there :)

Comment: Close... Forgot a ) on the second to last echo statement but other than that it's getting there. You have definitely shed light on the problem. Now I will put down a few things and work with what you have given me to solve this. Another +1 from me. The added code actually shifted the team names to the result for both team name and the first quarter but I think I can tinker a bit and get this to work.

Comment: Ok I am obviously a noob at SO. Can't give you 2 +1's but I would for your follow up!

Comment: Not really sure of what you mean and I'm too lazy to test it. However, I realized that the TD containing the team name also has the class yspscores. So maybe this TD is grabbed by find() while I didn't expect it to happen... Updating the code real quick.

Comment: [class=yspscores team] holds the team names [class=yspscores] holds all quarters and extra periods of overtime (note there may be several overtime periods in some cases) and [class=ysptblclbg6 total] actually produces the final score for the first TD then a "final" result next to the winning team on the second TD. It can be parsed that way... which is easier that the trouble you went through :( *BUT* the important piece of what you have given me is the MATCHING teams logic. So, here is what I will be doing with your code: 1) parse using classes 2)matching using your logic 3) put in html table